# How to bind repeating nested templates to complex models

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

Eventually I want to bind templates to a tree model, but to understand how binding works beyond object properties (simple or chained), lists, and maps, I've created a two-level set of repeating templates bound to a corresponding Dart model. Each item in the outer list contains an inner list.

```
o1
  a
  b
o2
  c
  d
```

When I select an inner item (for example 'd'), the click handler highlights the item and appends an Inner object 'e' to the 'o2' Outer object's list. Inspecting the model in the debugger shows that 'e' has been added to the model, but it is not being added as an 'li' element to the HTML list. How do I revise my code so that the inner template detects the change?

HTML

```dart
<polymer-element name="nested-templates">
<template>
    <style>
        :host { display: block; height: 100%; }

        ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

        li { font-size: 0.85rem; padding-left: 0.75rem;  }
        li:hover { background: lightgrey; cursor: pointer; }
        li.selected { color: red; }
    </style>

    <div>
        <template repeat="{{o in outer}}">
            <strong>{{o.name}}</strong>
            <ul>
                <template repeat="{{i in o.inner}}">
                    <li id="{{i.name}}" on-click="{{innerClickHandler}}">{{i.name}}</li>
                </template>
            </ul>
        </template>
    </div>
</template>

<script type="application/dart" src="nested_templates.dart"></script>
```

Dart

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

@CustomTag('nested-templates')
class NestedTemplates extends PolymerElement {

    @observable List<Outer> outer = toObservable([
            new Outer('o1', [ new Inner('a'), new Inner('b')]),
            new Outer('o2', [ new Inner('c'), new Inner('d')])
    ], deep: true);

    void innerClickHandler(Event e, Map detail, HtmlElement target) {
        target.classes.add('selected');

        outer[1].inner.add(new Inner('e'));
    }

    NestedTemplates.created() : super.created();
}

class Inner extends Observable {
    String name;

    Inner(this.name);
}

class Outer extends Observable {
    String name;
    List<Inner> inner;

    Outer(this.name, this.inner);
}
```

pubspec.yaml

```dart
dependencies:
  ...
  polymer: 0.10.1+1
  polymer_expressions: 0.11.0
  ...
dependency_overrides:
  polymer_expressions: '0.11.0'
```

Comment: Did you try this.deliverChanges()? Or this.dirtyCheck()? (Once the model has been changed...)

Comment: @Vloz Either function has no effect if added right after the line 'outer[1].inner.add(new Inner('e'));' (this.dirtyCheck() generates a warning in the Dart Editor that it is static. I used Observable.dirtyCheck() instead.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `toObservable()` for your inner too

```dart
new Outer('o1', toObservable([ new Inner('a'), new Inner('b')])),
```

Comment: Thanks. It's out of scope for this question, but I can't see how binding to templates would be a solution for generalized tree models which have varying depth.

Comment: Good question! Would be interesting if a tree-node can be used within its definition. I think Pixelate has a Polymer.dart tree control. Should be worth a look. (I'm on my phone now but shouldn't be hard to find)